# Flask - Checkbox is not holding value after submit

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a problem with setting up single checkbox in flask application, which I would like to use checkbox as button to control LED diode. When it's checked, light is on and when it's not, it's off. The mechanism already works, but every-time, when I check the checkbox, the checkbox will uncheck itself (It submits the checkbox). I need it to hold its actual value after the submit.

I tried to use jinja2 If statement to put attribute "checked" into HTML code, but it didn't work. If I could read and change the value directly from python, I would be able to easily modify it with something like this

```
{% if value="on"%} checked {% else %} "" {% endif %}
```

but I really don't know how :/.

autocomplete="off" doesn't work in this case.

I don't want to use additional variables, when this code already needs changes.

```
<input onchange="$('#check').submit();" type="checkbox" name="ledcheck" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck" {% dunno what to write here pls help :c %}/>


if 'ledcheck' in request.form:
    if database['actValues']['digital']['led'] == 1:
        database['actValues']['digital']['led'] = 0
        a.digital_write(LED_PIN,0)
    else:
        database['actValues']['digital']['led'] = 1
        a.digital_write(LED_PIN,1)
```

Whole code is on [GitHub here](https://github.com/TheLupp/Erasmus28).

Comment: Is there some kind of database where the state of checkbox is stored? Please show that code, as well as python function that handles the form.

Comment: @gittert Hey! Of course that there is! I added [GitHub URL](https://github.com/TheLupp/Erasmus28), where is the project stored.

Comment: What you probably need to do, after submit and following get request is read value from db, and pass it with render template, to get checked="yes" in the checkbox.

Comment: @gittert Ya, I was thinking about something but this too, but I don't really want to pass another variable into template. I think that there have to be option in flask which helps with this problem (or in JInja2), but I really don't know how.

Comment: Maybe store in session cookie and populate checkbox after page reload with jacascript?

Comment: @gittert The web will be displayed on more than one device, so session cookie is not available option .. I guess :/ BTW: Thank you for replying!

Comment: You want the same checkbox on client B to be checked automatically within seconds if that checkbox is checked on client A?

Comment: @gittert Yes. It should work as slider button. Like this: "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp". The core is checkbox.

Comment: To solve this I still would try to store the value in db and pass it to clients. I think you need js/ajax to 'push' the value to connected clients. Can't help you with that though.

Comment: Is it possible to create the checkbox via Flask? If it was possible I would be able to easily manage the checkbox. @gittert

Comment: Sure. You can create a form with on or more checkboxes, instantiate the form and pass it to render_template. Have a look at https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms for a nice example.